# Registering with consul servers vs consul clients

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, microservices, consul

I am creating a spring boot microservices application with 3 microservices. 
I'm using consul for discovery. I have only a single data centre with 4 hosts.
 **Should I have 3 microservices connecting to 3 consul agents(clients) in their respective localhosts and a consul server running on the remaining one host?**
It is mentioned that a cluster should have more than one server. Is it applicable in above situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your services should connect to an agent on localhost.

Consul servers should be run in a cluster. A 3 node cluster can handle 1 node failure, a 5 node cluster can handle 2 nodes failing. See https://www.consul.io/docs/internals/consensus.html#deployment_table

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the cluster is recommended to have more than 1 server and the microservices can connect to an agent on localhost.